# Setting large images in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I want to put images in UIScrollView. However, the problem is that when I try to put an image larger than UIScrollView, UIScrollView shows the upper part of images. I would like the scrollview to show the bottom part of the image. Right now, I have the following code:

```
let imgBot1 = UIImage(named:"Img1.jpg");
let imgBot2 = UIImage(named:"Img4.jpg");
let imgBot3 = UIImage(named:"Img5.jpg");

//Adding UIImage in UIImageView
let imgView1 = UIImageView(image:imgBot1)
let imgView2 = UIImageView(image:imgBot2)
let imgView3 = UIImageView(image:imgBot3)     

//creating UIScrollView
let scrView2 = UIScrollView()

scrView2.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.height/2,
self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)

//content size of the scrollview
scrView2.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width*3, self.view.frame.height)

//Size and place of UIImageView
imgView1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
imgView2.frame = CGRectMake(width, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
imgView3.frame = CGRectMake(width*2, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)


//adding the scrollview to the view
self.view.addSubview(scrView2)

scrView2.addSubview(imgView1)
scrView2.addSubview(imgView2)
scrView2.addSubview(imgView3)

scrView2.pagingEnabled = true


//Initial location of the scrollview
scrView2.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
```

I would like to know how I can make the scrollview to show the bottom part of the image, and not the top part. Will you help me out?

Answer (score -1):

I made this code, hope it will work for you. I used the storyboard, made a scrollView, added an imageView and added constrains to the image view to stick to the edges (don't know it that's necessary).

```
imageView = UIImage(named: "image")
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: image.image!.size.height)
```

Comment: totoajax, thanks for the input, but I would like to do this without using the storyboard. Will you tell me how?

Comment: It will work anyway, I just wanted to tel you how I did it so if it don't work for you, maybe you would be able to fix the problem. At least try, you will make it work.